# Как правильно настроить конфигурационный файл в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Как правильно настроить конфигурационный файл в Yii2?

Нашел только часть описания, что за что отвечает:

```
id - уникальный индекс приложения, который отличает его от других.
basePath - корневая папка приложения
bootstrap - массив компонент начальной загрузки
language - язык приложения
components - настройка компонентов приложения
params - параметры приложения
modules - подключение модулей приложения
```

---

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'o8fpfN3qM5656545454545464646',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}

return $config;
```

Comment: А что еще вы ожидаете увидиеть в ответе? Вы все перечислили.... Конфиг файл сразу после установки `basic` и `advanced` уже настроен на базовую работу....работоспособен и функционален.......А вы уже по мере необходимости будете добавлять в него все новые и новые пункты, например [компоненты приложения](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/structure-application-components.md) , [модули приложения](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/structure-modules.md) или [маршрут](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/runtime-routing.md) и другое

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Кажется я начал все понимать или вспоминать, спасибо.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  а почему 'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__), указана как __DIR__ - то есть, та директория в которой находится сам файл web.php? Разве это и есть корневая директория приложения?

Comment: `dirname` - Возвращает имя родительского каталога из указанного пути. а `__DIR__ ` указывает на директорию файла, то есть на `config`.....в итоге `dirname` директории `config` указывает на корень приложения....... вот если бы там было написано просто `__DIR__` вот тогда да... была бы незадача